# How to get value from input element and use it dynamically in async fetch function?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, async-await, fetch-api

Here in the URL the word should be dynamic, but when I get the value from the input tag with `id=search`. It returns 404 error but the API link is correct. Can anyone help me to achieve my task in fetch API.

```
const meaning = document.querySelector("#meaning");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
window.location.href = "/"
})

async function getWord() {
    const search = document.querySelector("#search").value;
    const url = `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${search}`
try {
    const getUrl = await fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
    });
    // console.log(getUrl);
    const jsonUrl = await getUrl.json();
    console.log(jsonUrl);
    return jsonUrl
} catch (error) {
    alert("Please enter the correct word")
}
}
 
const word = await getWord();
console.log(word);
```

I am unable to get a meaning of the word that I have been searching.

Comment: `const word = await getWord();` you're running `getWord` when there's been no chance for any input

Comment: have you considered adding an event listener?

Comment: The word being searched, `${search}`, is passed as part of the path of the GET request. More usually it  would be passed as a query parameter in the url. How is the server routing coded to identify the word being searched for?

Comment: Your code for function `getWord()` is correct. Question is how you are binding your function call to any element?

Answer (score 0):

You have a clear understanding of the JSON response received from the GET request.

#### Array and Item

start with `[`. it means `array` of object data.
So next character will start `{`. It means first item of object.

[image]

#### Hierarchy (Parent -> Child -> Grand Child)

If you want to get "A large body of salt water." definition

To retrieve it this syntax will get it.

```
Data[0]["meanings"][0]["definitions"][0]["definition"]
```

[image]

##### Preparation

#1 Install Chrome [JSON Viewer](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh) extension for viewing JSON data in Chrome

#2 VS Code extension [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) for running HTML local server

##### Demo HTML

Save as "word.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dictionary App</title>
    <style>
        #meaning {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="wordInput" placeholder="Enter a word">
    <button id="button">Get Meaning</button>
    <div id="meaning"></div>

    <script>
        const button = document.querySelector("#button");
        const meaning = document.querySelector("#meaning");

        button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
            const word = document.querySelector("#wordInput").value;
            const url = `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`;

            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const data = await response.json();

                displayMeanings(data);
            } catch (error) {
                meaning.innerHTML = `<p>Error fetching data: ${error.message}</p>`;
            }
        });

        function displayMeanings(data) {
            meaning.innerHTML = '';

            data.forEach(entry => {
                entry.meanings.forEach(meaningEntry => {
                    const partOfSpeech = document.createElement('h3');
                    partOfSpeech.textContent = meaningEntry.partOfSpeech;

                    meaning.appendChild(partOfSpeech);

                    meaningEntry.definitions.forEach(def => {
                        const definition = document.createElement('p');
                        definition.textContent = `Definition: ${def.definition}`;

                        meaning.appendChild(definition);

                        if (def.example) {
                            const example = document.createElement('p');
                            example.textContent = `Example: ${def.example}`;
                            example.style.fontStyle = 'italic';

                            meaning.appendChild(example);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

##### Running html

By clicking "Go Live" from VS Code with "word.html"
[image]

##### Opening by Chrome

```
Enter `sea` word then press `Get Meaning` button
```

[image]

#### Relation data source, code and display

A collection of name/value pairs (often realized as an object in various programming languages).
An ordered list of values (often realized as an array).

When you have a JSON array, you're dealing with the second structure: an ordered list of values. These values can be numbers, strings, booleans, other arrays, or objects. In JavaScript, the forEach() method is commonly used to iterate over arrays, including arrays in JSON format.

Here's a breakdown of how forEach() is used for data extraction from a JSON array:

[image]